# Grails filters after action return value

Tags: grails, filter

Should I return boolean from  **"after"** action of grails filter?
I think it is useless,I need confirmation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience I didn't need to either.  The "after" filter runs after the controller logic and before the rendering of the template.  The rendering phase will occur regardless of what you return from the after filter.

Answer (score 0):

Returning boolean false in the before closure will prevent all future filters and the action from executing.

http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/single.html#filterTypes

As Tri points out the return value of the after closure has no effect.